# same font-size,but chrome render these label to different size

Tags: css

[image: bug pic]
I set the div style  `font-size:24px` ,but the chrome render it to `36px`. I don`t know why. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: check in chrome setting-> Show advanced settings->web content

Comment: I guess the reason is mix of scalable options in the your viewport. Try to play with it, f.e. put just `initial_scale` at first and see the result